# Start function JS when you reach a specific div

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code found on the internet, that run well in Chrome and Safari. Only in Firefox and IE the code will not run. Is there an alternative?

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop );
        if( pTop > oTop ){
            start_count();
        }
    });
});

function start_count(){
    alert('start_count');
    //Add your code here
}
```

Comment: I tried it in all versions of IE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('.wordpress').offset().top - $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){

       var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
        if( scrollTop > oTop ){
            start_count();
        }
    });
});
```